# Infinite size nicematrix

Tags: nicematrix

I am trying to write a nicematrix version of this tridiagonal (infinite size) matrix, as the pmatrix environment renders a very ugly version

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    -\lambda & \lambda             & 0                    & 0       & \dots  \\
    \mu      & -(\lambda+\mu)      & \lambda              & 0       &        \\
    0        & 2\mu                & -(\lambda+2\mu)      & \lambda &        \\
    \vdots   &                     & \ddots               & \ddots  & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

So I naively wrote

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    -\lambda & \lambda             & 0                    & 0       & \Cdots  \\
    \mu      & -(\lambda+\mu)      & \lambda              & 0       &        \\
    0        & 2\mu                & -(\lambda+2\mu)      & \lambda &        \\
    \Vdots   &                     & \Ddots               & \Ddots  & \Ddots
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
```

But the result does not work at all

[image]

I am guessing the problem comes from a lack of indication for an end to my \Ddots. But then how am I supposed to manage infinite size matrices ?

Edit

I am providing a complete minimal example, with the document class I am working in.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    -\lambda & \lambda             & 0                    & 0       & \Cdots  \\
    \mu      & -(\lambda+\mu)      & \lambda              & 0       &        \\
    0        & 2\mu                & -(\lambda+2\mu)      & \lambda &        \\
    \Vdots   &                     & \Ddots               & \Ddots  & \Ddots
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The results of compilation look a little bit different to the pictures I provided because I had a font package. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Could you put your code into complete examples with the necessary packages (and the class that you've used)?

Comment: Done. I gave the complete minimal example but the differences are annecdotal. This was to be expected as it clearly looks like an internal problem of nicematrix

Comment: Command `\Ddots` are intended to be drawn between two not empty matrix nodes. So you should stich with first code fragment which gives to my opinion nice looking result. What you after seems to be features request. Hopefully author of package will see your question and provide some fix to your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands `\Ldots`, `\Cdots`, `\Vdots`, `\Ddots`, and `\Iddots` are intended to be used between cells that are not empty. So you can make the cells `\NotEmpty`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    -\lambda  & \lambda        & 0               & 0         & \Cdots  \\
    \mu       & -(\lambda+\mu) & \lambda         & 0         &         \\
    0         & 2\mu           & -(\lambda+2\mu) & \lambda   &         \\
    \Vdots    &                & \Ddots          & \Ddots    & \Ddots  \\
    \NotEmpty &                &                 & \NotEmpty & \NotEmpty
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1! I use `nice matrix` occasionally and wasn't aware for `NotEmpty` command. Good to know!

Comment: Was not aware either of this command. Thx !

Answer (score 2):

With `\phantom` is perhaps enough for you?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    -\lambda & \lambda             & 0                    & 0       & \Cdots  \\
    \mu      & -(\lambda+\mu)      & \lambda              & 0       &        \\
    0        & 2\mu                & -(\lambda+2\mu)      & \lambda &        \\
    \Vdots   &                     & \Ddots               & \Ddots  & \Ddots\\
\phantom{}&\phantom{}&\phantom{}&\phantom{.}&\phantom{.}
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the meaning of that \phantom command ?

Comment: @20-sided-dice you have a description of this command section 3.7.1 in the `lshort` documentation or in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212710/fill-space-created-by-phantom-with-other-text